# Profile Picture in wordpress using JSON

Tags: ios, json, wordpress

I'm working on wordpress that gonna be used as webserver for mobile app(in my case is iOS),
but i want to ask how user can add/edit the profile picture in mobile app, i'm thinking about using JSON for send the picture file, i did some research and found something like gravatar.com that can be used for add profile picture but my problem is how the user can add/edit from mobile app ?

ps : the mobile app build on objective c + JSON.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a http post request and add image as a body of the request.

similar to this

```
NSString *boundary = @"AaB03x";
NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];

[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"imageFile.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n",IMAGE_MIME_TYPE] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"pass the file path here"]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//////////////////////////////PREPARING POST REQUEST BODY/////////////////////////////////////////////

NSMutableURLRequest *uploadRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                      initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url to server"]
                                      cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                      timeoutInterval:45];

[uploadRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[uploadRequest setValue:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[uploadRequest setHTTPBody:postbody];
```